# How to remove Horizontal bar at bottom of the page??

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

While creating a webpage with Bootstrap 3, i got a horizontal bar at the bottom of the page.
And i'm newbie to bootstrap so i can't figure it out how to remove the horizontal bar.
This is what i'm trying to say:

```
codepan  http://codepen.io/Kishan93/pen/wWBdyW
```

Can anyone  help me to remove it??

And just for reference image size is 1920 x 872 px

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the div with class .row
row class has -15px margin left and right, and if it's not properly nested, it creates vertical scroll

Comment: Thanks for solving the problem...Can you tell how to post question with link??I don't know how to put link while asking the question,because i'm new to Stack Exchange..